# Parameter b such that $det(A-bI)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve questions asking me for a parameter such that $det(A-bI)=0$, where I is the identity matrix. I can do it using trial and error but I am struggling to think of a matrix property that would allow me to solve this question in a systematic way. Can someone please suggest something?

Comment: You have a formula for the determinant, do you not? What's stopping you from using that?

Comment: This is called a characteristic equation, it's only a polynomial of degree $n$, where $n$ is the size of your matrix.  Ofcourse solving such equation would be harder if the roots are not rational or even real.

Comment: Just let $b$ an eigenvalue of $A$. Then this determinant is zero. So put $A$ into triagonal form. Then the diagonal elements are the eigenvalues.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am sorry for not being specific. I am just asking in general because I would like to understand the method thats generalisable instead of just doing this one question. I am indeed given two parts, one has A which is 2x2, in the other A is  3x3

Comment: $det(A−bI)=0$ means that b is an eigenvalue of $A$. There is no systematic way to find such $b$. There are numeric methods, like power iteration, but this algorithm, for example, is sure to converge only if $A$ is diagonalizable. For square matrices with $4$ or less coefficients per column/line, it is feasible.

Comment: Since the matrices in question usually have order $n\le 4$, here even $3\times 3$ or less, one can (and does) just solve the polynomial equation of degree $n$. So in this sense there is a systematic way to find such $b$. But better is to put $A$ by similarity transformations into upper-triangular form. Then all eigenvalues $b$ are on the diagonal and you have them explicitly.